# Los adjetivos aplicados a un grupo

Tags: gramática

Tengo la siguiente oración:

> For the curious, more information can be found in the following
>     link.

Y se aplica la palabra "curious" a un grupo de gente que es curiosa. Esto es usado con frecuencia en inglés. Pero, ¿se puede usar esto en español? Por ejemplo:

> Para los curiosos, se puede encontrar más información en el siguiente sitio.

---

In English, we write

> For the curious, more information can be found in the following
>     link.

and attribute that phrase "For the curious..." to a group of people.  Can we translate that as "Para los curiosos..." in Spanish?

Answer (score 3):

Sí, es correcto utilizar el adjetivo con el artículo para indicar un objeto o persona (singular) o un grupo de cosas o personas (plural) que tienen ese atributo.

> Para los curiosos, se puede encontrar más información en el siguiente sitio.

es una frase perfectamente válida.